# Can Lego Education WeDo 2.0 be controlled without using the app?

Tags: education, wedo

I would like to use WeDo 2.0 creations with a simple controller that would turn the motor on/off as in the Lego Education Simple and Powered Machines. Is this possible in WeDo 2.0 or do you have to use the app ?

Comment: I don't think Lego made a physical controller for their WeDo set, and that no one else did either. The same thing goes for Lego Control+, it has an app but no actual controller. And for Lego Boost too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible currently using any of the hardware and software provided officially by TLG. However, there are several solutions that might work for you if you have a spare Arduino or Raspberry Pi around and are willing to do a little programming.

If you aren't aware, all of the Powered Up elements communicate via a Bluetooth protocol that TLG provides [documentation](https://lego.github.io/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs/) for. There are several open source projects that make use of the API to interact with Powered Up devices.

If you have an Arduino available, you could try the [Legoino](https://github.com/corneliusmunz/legoino) project. This is capable of interacting with both Powered Up remotes and Powered Up hubs, so you can program it to interface between the two and provide remove control. Here's a video showing that setup in action controlling Boost:

[image: Legoino Boost control example]

If you have a Raspberry Pi or spare computer around, you might be more interested [node-poweredup](https://github.com/nathankellenicki/node-poweredup) or [pylgbst](https://github.com/undera/pylgbst).